# How to log "new pnp devices" events to console on Windows?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, plug-and-play

I want to write something like `nestat` (that log new tcp connections to console) but for pnp devices with powershell.

Is there an API method "to subscribe to some kind of events bus" specific to PnP and get "connected" and "disconnected" events?

Or only one way to achive this is looping with `Get-PnpDevice` and "manually" seacrh for the differences?

Comment: Why is this closed? Seems like a very reasonable question to ask and definitely helped solve my problem. The fact that the OP tries to explain the different approaches they investigated does not disqualify the question, imo.

Comment: @method, reopened with your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WMI events to do this.  For example, here is one way to do it (seems over-complicated, so maybe someone can improve on it):

```
$addIdentifier = "WMI.PnpAddEvent"
$removeIdentifier = "WMI.PnpRemoveEvent"

$addAction = { $pnpEntity = $EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance; Write-Host "`nPNPEvent: Plugged In`nCaption: $($pnpEntity.Caption)`nPNPDeviceID: $($pnpEntity.PNPDeviceID)`n" }
$addQuery = "SELECT * FROM __instancecreationevent WITHIN 5 WHERE targetinstance isa 'Win32_PnPEntity'"

$removeAction = { $pnpEntity = $EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance; Write-Host "`nPNPEvent: Unplugged`nCaption: $($pnpEntity.Caption)`nPNPDeviceID: $($pnpEntity.PNPDeviceID)`n" }
$removeQuery = "SELECT * FROM __instancedeletionevent WITHIN 5 WHERE targetinstance isa 'Win32_PnPEntity'"

$addEventArgs = @{
    Query            = $addQuery
    SourceIdentifier = $addIdentifier
    SupportEvent     = $true
    Action           = $addAction
}

$removeEventArgs = @{
    Query            = $removeQuery
    SourceIdentifier = $removeIdentifier
    SupportEvent     = $true
    Action           = $removeAction
}

Register-WmiEvent @addEventArgs
Register-WmiEvent @removeEventArgs
```

Now, when you add/remove a device, you'll get output like this in the console:

```
PNPEvent: Unplugged
Caption: Apple iPhone
PNPDeviceID: USB\VID_05AC&PID_12A8&MI_00\E&2491F388&0&0000    

PNPEvent: Plugged In
Caption: Apple iPhone
PNPDeviceID: USB\VID_05AC&PID_12A8&MI_00\E&2491F388&0&0000
```

A couple of things to keep in mind:

- The event registrations last for the current session only
- You need to run this from an elevated prompt

As mentioned, the registrations should be cancelled when your session ends, but if you want to do it manually, you can do it like this:

```
$addIdentifier, $removeIdentifier | ForEach-Object { Unregister-Event -Force -SourceIdentifier $_ }
```

Comment: Thank you! Register-WmiEvent call returns an error: Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Query' is specified more than once . PSVersion is 5.1

Comment: I think that was a formatting issue, where it looked like the registration was on one line, but should be two separate calls.  I updated the example to what it should be.